# Erro ao acessar o Hive no Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) on Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: hive

Boa Noite Pessoal,
Estou tentando acessar o Hive pelo Hortonworks Data Platform e está aparecendo um erro. Poderiam me ajudar?

[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# hive
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.5.0-292/0/hive-log4j.properties

hive-log4j.properties:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hive.log.threshold=ALL
hive.root.logger=INFO,DRFA
hive.log.dir=${java.io.tmpdir}/${user.name}
hive.log.file=hive.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hive.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=${hive.log.threshold}

#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#
# Use the PidDailyerRollingFileAppend class instead if you want to use separate log files
# for different CLI session.
#
# log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PidDailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex= 30
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize = 256MB
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout


# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t]: %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8

#custom logging levels
#log4j.logger.xxx=DEBUG

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter


log4j.category.DataNucleus=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.Datastore=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.Datastore.Schema=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Datastore=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Plugin=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.MetaData=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Query=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.General=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Enhancer=ERROR,DRFA


# Silence useless ZK logs
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn=WARN,DRFA
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO=WARN,DRFA
```

Comment: `DailyRollingFileAppender` não suporta `maxBackupIndex`, creio que só `RollingFileAppender` suporte.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigada. O que devo fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza se é isso, pode ser a versão do `org.apache.log4j` que você adicionou, se for no servidor pode ser que a versão é mais antiga, não entendo muito

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro verifique no ambari se o Hive esta iniciado, bem como o Zookeeper, Ranger, HDFS, YARN e MapReduce. Poce acessar o ambari pelo endereço http://localhost:8080/

Depois de tudo iniciado, acesso a sandbox por ssh (ssh root@sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -p 2222) e entre no hive utilizando o beeline como informado abaixo:

beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" -nhive -phive

Caso queira utilizar o hivecli, deve informar usuário e senha:

hive -nhive -phive

Caso ainda não consiga, envie o erro completo.